# How to remove alphabets and extract numbers using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to remove alphabets and extract numbers using regex in python?

```
import re
l=["098765432123 M","123456789012"]
s = re.findall(r"(?<!\d)\d{12}", l)
print(s)
```

> Expected Output:

123456789012

Comment: `re.findall` does not take three parameters (not in that form, anyway).  Is that a string containing both parts, or a list of strings, or are you actually calling it in that way?

Comment: Uhhhh, what's that 3rd argument you're passing to `findall` supposed to be doing?

Comment: What is the input? If a list, use `[x for x in l if re.search(r'^\d{12}$', x)]`

Comment: thank u so much @ Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: So which solution are you going to use in the end? Do you need to match any item with 12 or more consecutive digits not followed with a space + uppercase letter, or do you want to only keep items that only consist of 12 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a negative lookahead assertion, if as stated you want to use regex only.

```
l=["098765432123 M","123456789012"]
res=[]
for a in l:
    s = re.search(r"(?<!\d)\d{12}(?! [a-zA-Z])", a)
    if s is not None:
        res.append(s.group(0))
```

The result would then be:

```
['123456789012']
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to have *filtered* list, consisting elements with pure digits, use `filter` with `str.isdigit`:

```
list(filter(str.isdigit, l))
```

Or as @tobias_k suggested, `list` comprehension is always your friend:

```
[s for s in l if s.isdigit()]
```

Output:

```
['123456789012']
```

Comment: Without lambda: `list(filter(str.isdigit, l))` Or a list comprehension: `[s for s in l if s.isdigit()]` And maybe add `and len(s) == 12` for the length constraint. Also, maybe `strip` strings first.

Comment: @tobias_k Ah, of course. Got too used to using `lambda`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To keep only digits you can do `re.findall('\d',s)`, but you'll get a list:

```
s = re.findall('\d', "098765432123 M")
print(s)
> ['0', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: i want to extract only the numbers which does not contain any alphabet agter a space

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear, you want to ignore the whole string if there is a alphabetic character in it? Or do you still want to extract the numbers of a string with both numbers and alphabetic characters in it?

If you want to find all numbers, and always find the longest number use this:

```
regex = r"\d+"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

`\d` will search for digits, `+` will find one or more of the defined characters, and will always find the longest consecutive line of these characters.

If you only want to find strings without alphabets:

```
import re
regex = r"[a-zA-Z]"
test_str = ("098765432123 M", "123456789012")
for x in test_str:
    if not re.search(regex, x):
        print(x)
```